# How to implement my models relationships and ensure only one to one - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, models, relation

I am very new to Laravel and frameworks so I am in the process of learning a lot.

A user after logging in goes to a page where a form is displayed. I wish for this form to only be displayed if they have not filled this in previously.

My tables are like this

```
User                         Registration Q's
---------------------------------------------------
user_id                        reg_id
name                           q1
email                          q2
password                       q3
                               user_id
```

**My user.php model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function userq()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Userreq');
    }
```

**userregq.php Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class userregq extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'userregq';
  public $timestamps = false;

  public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me to ensure that only one user has one registration questionnaire and it is only showed if they do not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think first you need to redesign your database since many-to-many relationship fits better. A user can answer multiple questions and one question can be asked to many users and you also need to store an answer so I would redesign to this:

```
User         Answer         Question
---------------------------------------
user_id      answer_id      question_id
name         user_id        question
email        question_id
password     answer
```

And then write your Eloquent models.

When user logs in you retrieve records from answer table with logged in user id and if there are none, display him the questionnaire.

As you are new to laravel you might wanna check these great video tutorials by Jeffrey Way at [Laracasts Laravel 5 Fundamentals](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals).